# Is android ViewModelStore a dependency injector

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Hi? How should I perceive androids architecture component ViewModelStore does it invalidate the need to inject ViewModels using a dependency injection library?﻿

Answer (score 1):

[ViewModels are intimately tied to Activities or Fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html), things with an Android Lifecycle. Because they are so closely tied to these objects they have functions, features and needs that a dependency injection library does not provide. The most important feature a ViewModel provides is the ability to retain its state on configuration changes but not on separate launches of the Activity, which is what developers need most of the time. When you need state which is saved between separate launches of an activity, that's when you employ a database layer, such as the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

So the simple answer is YES. It is best to use

```
ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(MyViewModel.class)
```

to instantiate and lookup your view models.

Comment: It seems like this answer provide a solution to different question?

Answer (score 1):

ViewModelStore is not at all related to dependency injection of ViewModel. It is a container of ViewModel objects of a particular owner. You can get ViewModelStore of an activity or fragment by using of method of ViewModelStores.

```
  ViewModelStore vms = ViewModelStores.of(this);
```

ViewModelStore gives you control over life time of viewmodel objects of a particular owner if you need.

Comment: Thanks @Arnav, so I don't need to manually put the `ViewModel` to `ViewModelStore`? It's assigned to the store once it's created for certain lifecycle owner?